# Razor form on a facebook tab page

Tags: javascript, facebook, razor

I am trying to execute a form inside an Facebook tab. What have I tried among many things:

It seems like Request.HttpMethod == "POST" is not working as usual. @message prints out on pageload.
I have tried to add alert to before  return $('form').valid(). This is not being executed.

Any ideas of issue or another workaround.

Code:

```
@{
    var message = string.Empty;
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
        message = "SUBMITTED";
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="form">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    {
        <p class="formFinish">
            @message
        </p>
    }

    <div class="row">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" class="required" minlength="4" maxlength="30" />
    </div>
    <div class="newGame row">
        <button class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('form').attr('enctype', "multipart/form-data");
        $('form').on('submit', function () {
            return $('form').valid()
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there! Just wanted to find out if the provided answer solved your question. If it did, accepting the answer would help people with similar issues in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something obvious, it doesn't seem that you're sending a post. You've got no actual form there, just a div with the class of "form", and your "Submit" button is just a button that doesn't appear to have any action associated with it. You're going to need to actually post something if you want the page to get a post request.

EDIT: Here's working code, I just had to change your "div class='form'" into an actual form element with method "post". Note that I didn't fix your usage of jQuery validate, but now that the form is actually generating a post request, you should be well on your way.

```
@{
    var message = string.Empty;
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
        message = "SUBMITTED";
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    {
        <p class="formFinish">
            @message
        </p>
    }

    <div class="row">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" class="required" minlength="4" maxlength="30" />
    </div>
    <div class="newGame row">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser. This is just to make  things as simple as possible. next step is to write some c# inside: if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST"). Get value form name="Name" etc. Make sense?

Comment: No, because you're still not generating a post anywhere. Unless there's code missing, when you click that button nothing is being executed, so you're never sending a post back to the page. My point is that I think your if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST") would work fine if the page were actually receiving a post... you're just never actually making any request, post or not. Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: I am sure your are right. I have used this code before. Ex: http://www.games2share.dk/pages/glemt-password.aspx try typing email and btn.Thanks

Comment: By editing the div and turning it into an actual form, I got your code to work, although I didn't implement the validation. I'm going to edit my original answer with the working code, so that if it works for you it can hopefully be accepted.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your codes. Your code is making the postback for sure. For some reason the MESSAGE is being displayed already on page load. I am preaty sure its somthing with Facebook tab setup. But still struggeling :-/